# Number of child processes in parent process C/C++, LINUX

Tags: c++

I am programming in Linux using C/C++. I have a problem, i am trying to find a function or something in order to get number of child processes in parent process.

Help me please
Thanks

Comment: Couldn't the parent just count them as they get forked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if POSIX defines a function for this, but you could always count them in a global variable yourself, just add 1 after every fork on the parent, and set it to 0 on the child..

Comment: it is not possible to use global variable, remember that child clones the whole code and the global variable becomes useless.

Comment: @VaheMusinyan: That's why he said, "and set it to 0 on the child".

Comment: Still does not ring the bell. If you set to 0 it does not affect on the global variable. Can anyone give me some code example?

Comment: A child process is not able to decrease the parent's global variable. The parent and the child have different stack frames meaning that the global variable is not global between them. To have a process-global variable you should use shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `procfs` : count the number of directories in `/proc/[mypid]/task` and you have the number of child processes started.

See [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
int globalVariable = 0;

main() {
  pid_t pID = fork();
  if (pID == 0) { //child
    globalVariable = 0;
    cout << "Child Process" << end;
  }
  else if (pID < 0) { //failed to fork
    cerr << "Failed to fork" << endl;
    exit(1);
    // Throw exception
  }
  else { // parent
    cout << "Parent Process:";
    ++globalVariable;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'ps' command with the --ppid option to list all the child processes and then count them using wc -l

ps --ppid  | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in C++11, could easily be adapted to pre-C++11 or C if needed. You need to check every process in the system and see who it's parent is:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::to_string;

bool is_number(const string& s) {
  string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
  for (; it != s.end() && isdigit(*it); ++it) {
  }

  return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

int count_children(const pid_t pid) {
  DIR* dir;
  if ((dir = opendir("/proc"))) {
    int num_children = 0;
    for (struct dirent* ent; (ent = readdir(dir));) {
      if (is_number(ent->d_name)) {
        ifstream ifs(string("/proc/" + string(ent->d_name) + "/stat").c_str());
        string word;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
          ifs >> word;
        }

        if (word == to_string(pid)) {
          ++num_children;
        }
      }
    }

    closedir(dir);

    return num_children;
  }

  perror("could not open directory");

  return INT_MAX;
}
```

Another possible option in the parent process is to create a variable initialised to zero in the parent process and incrementing it every time you fork and decrementing every time you receive a SIGCHLD.

Comment: Always take 4 lines is fragile ?