# count processes made with fork

Tags: c, fork

How do I count how many processes I've made using fork? Some of them are made inside child processes so I can't just count when I exit. Is there a way to pass certain variables around aside from exit statuses?

Comment: Some kind of counter in shared memory, or other IPC mechanism?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659501/number-of-child-processes-in-parent-process-c-c-linux might get you started

Comment: that's what I thought but I also have child processes in child processes which my parent would be blind to.

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_open.html) have an example on how to use shared memory. Open the shared memory object and memory map it in every process, use it as an `int` pointer and increase it in all processes.

To help with race conditions, you could use [POSIX semaphores](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/semaphore.h.html).

Answer (score 0):

you could use a global variable yourself, just adding 1 after every fork with condition

`if((pid = fork()) >= 0)`

with a mechanism to protect the variable like `mutex`.

Comment: Won't it raise the mechanism of "Copy on write" ?